# mySQL Datatype for storing numbers with abbreviated suffix?

Tags: mysql

What would be the proper datatype for a number with an abbreviated suffix (such as m for million)?

For example, normally the datatype for **100.20** would be: `DECIMAL` of 5,2.

What should the datatype be for **100.20M**? Is there a proper datatype similar to `DECIMAL` that would maintain such rigidness?

Comment: I would have a separate column for the abbreviation.

Comment: @hd1 that's insanity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no datatype that will "understand" the abbreviations.  If you want MySQL to treat the data as numbers (for expression evaluation or sorting) it is best for you to evaluate the abbreviaton yourself and store the number with all the digits, so 100.20M is 100200000-- specifying as many digits as your data will require.

Formatting it with the suffix is for the presentation layer, not the DB.

Comment: the last sentence answers this question nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I would store as DECIMAL with all digits (depending on minimum number) and then convert to string format as `100.20M`. It's better for sorting in future.

Comment: convert? How would I differentiate between million/billion. Do you mean enter them as the full number 1,000,000?

Comment: I would save 1000000, 1000000000 as a number. And then just simple Math to convert.

Comment: The numbers are currently in abbreviated format, so I would have to convert them twice. Maybe a `varchar` will do.

Comment: The numbers as of now are in the format of: 100M, so I would have to convert them to the long number, then store it, then unconvert them when I'm selected them.

Comment: 100M convert to 100000000 and store in the database and back from 100000000 convert to string 100M when you select it.